# A homeomorphism of topological groups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, topological-groups

Let $L/K$ be a Galois field extension and $(I, \leq)$ be the directed set of all finite Galois extensions $E$ of $K$ contained in $L$ (we say $E^{\prime}\leq E$ if $E^{\prime}\subseteq E$). 
If $E^{\prime}\leq E$ we have a homomorphism $${\rm Gal}(E/K)\to {\rm Gal}(E^{\prime}/K)$$ given by the obvious restriction. 
These give rise to an inverse system so we obtain the inverse limit $\Lambda:= \varprojlim {\rm Gal}(E/K)$.

We have a restriction homomorphism $G:={\rm Gal}(L/K) \to {\rm Gal}(E/K)$ for each $E\in I$. These combine to give a group isomorphism $$\theta: G\cong \Lambda.$$

I need to show that $\theta^{-1}$ is continuous. Here, I assume $G$ has the Krull topology and $\Lambda$ the product topology where each component of $\Lambda$ is discrete.

> Question: I want to show that it's enough to assume that $H$ is an open, *normal* subgroup of $G$. How can I show this, e.g. from the definition of the fundamental system of neighborhoods of the identity?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: A continuous bijective map between compact Hausdorff spaces is a homeomorphism.